# Windows XP flash unicode problem

Tags: xml, flash, encoding, utf-8, fusioncharts

We have fusion charts which is based on flash.

In Windows XP, characters in Flash are square boxes. In other OS it shows normally.

XML are sent to Flash using FlashVars.

You can check charts here: http://sociology.am/suren/node/1/webform-results/chart

And this is a code which is embedding chart. I have added BOM in the begining of DataXml.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="300" height="300" id="DrupalFusionChart_1"> 
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /> 
        <param name="movie" value="/suren/sites/all/modules/fusioncharts/FusionChartsFree/Charts/FCF_Pie3D.swf"/>       
        <param name="FlashVars" value="&chartWidth=300&chartHeight=300&debugMode=0&dataXML=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<graph caption='Тест Test Հաշվետվությունները ներկայացնում են%26amp;#10; հարկային մարմնին՝' decimalPrecision='0'>
<set name='էլեկտրոնային' value='42' color='AFD8F8'     />
<set name='առձեռն' value='5' color='F6BD0F'     />
<set name='փոստով' value='30' color='8BBA00'     />
<set name='' value='4' color='FF8E46'     />
</graph>
&registerWithJS=0" /> 
        <param name="quality" value="high" /> 
        <param name="wmode" value="window" /> 
        <embed src="/suren/sites/all/modules/fusioncharts/FusionChartsFree/Charts/FCF_Pie3D.swf" FlashVars="&chartWidth=300&chartHeight=300&debugMode=0&dataXML=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<graph caption='Тест Test Հաշվետվությունները ներկայացնում են%26amp;#10; հարկային մարմնին՝' decimalPrecision='0'>
<set name='էլեկտրոնային' value='42' color='AFD8F8'     />
<set name='առձեռն' value='5' color='F6BD0F'     />
<set name='փոստով' value='30' color='8BBA00'     />
<set name='' value='4' color='FF8E46'     />
</graph>
&registerWithJS=0" quality="high" width="300" height="300" name="DrupalFusionChart_1" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" wmode="window" /> 
    </object>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely that the font you are using does not have the characters to display. Try specfying "_sans" as the font on your flash chart. That should allow either OS to use the system sans-serif font to display the characters.